# VSE: Can I move an audio track in smaller increments than one frame?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am using Blender to mix the video from my camera with the audio from my external recording setup.  It works great mostly and I am very pleased with it.  But the problem is that I can't start the audio recorder an even number of thirtieths of a second from when I started the camera.  And Blender seems to only let me move the audio track in the VSE by whole frames (1/30 of a second).

Here are a couple screenshots:
[image]

The track on top is the external audio and the one on the bottom is the camera's audio.  Between the two screenshots I have only moved the audio track by one frame.  But as you can see, I need to move it by about 1/2 frame to line up the audio properly with the video.

**So can I move a track in the VSE by fractions of a frame?**

Comment: I have a sophisticating [solution](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48271/2843) for this problem as I faced it as well. The quick answer is: No, in Blender you can't align your audio more accurate, you'd need an external program like Audacity for this. But usually my method to match two audio files playing back in sync works quite well.

Comment: Here is a proposal on Right-Click Select. Put your vote there so we may have a solution in the future. [https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/4Fgbbc/](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/4Fgbbc/)

Answer (score 4):

Blenders VSE aligns clips to the frame, I don't know of any plans to change this.

I would suggest adjusting the audio clip in Audacity or other audio editing program where you can move the audio the desired amount from the start of the audio file.

Comment: I was afraid of that, the problem is I often have large amounts of audio and video to mix.

Comment: Had the same problem before. Maybe using a Custom Frame Rate with a higher FPS and a corresponding Framerate Base while fiddeling with the time remapping helps? Couldn't get it working on demand though... For me (handling only "speech footage") it never was too much of an issue though as in the end only one audio track mixed down in Audacity was used...

Comment: For me it would be obvious to have that option to turn of frame snapping or something like that. It is really necessary for professional editing. Is there a development goal to solve this problem? Is there a platform to "vote" for this feature?

Comment: @Prag you could add your suggestion to [rightclickselect](http://rightclickselect.com/), not sure if anyone is interested in making blender suitable for professional video editing.

Comment: @sambler Thanks. Do you think it is hard to implement that feature?

Comment: @Prag I'm not familiar with the code used so don't know what would be involved.  The [code for the sequencer](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/space_sequencer/) doesn't appear to be too large.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Blender 3.0. I found that in the "Time" section of the clip properties an adjustment can be made. I aligned the audio as close as I could then I adjusted the start offset and it seemed to do the trick for me. I use up to 6 audio tracks to align/synch all the video tracks in music videos. This worked for me. If the "echo" is gone it is in synch.