# How can I bake sound to f-curve but use pitch instead of volume?

Tags: audio, fcurves

I am doing a blender project to music and I have animated it to change with the music using the bake sound to f-curve function, but I need it to change using the pitch as the variable, instead of the volume. Is there a way of doing this?, it doesn't need to be using the bake sound to f-curve.

Comment: maybe this helps you? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49086/audio-bake-to-f-curves-fails-with-very-high-numbers/49163#49163

Comment: I think you'd want to search for FFT (fast fourier transform) software, where you could convert pitch to numerics.

Comment: Thanks Ill have a look at both of them.

Comment: Did you ever get a good answer on this? Super curious. Thanks!