# Generate a f-curve from another one

Tags: fcurves

How can I generate a f-curve from the upper and lower points of another f-curve?

(check out the image as example, I want to generate the green f-curve from the red f-curve)

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for the red curve? Is it a baked sound? I already [used](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/48271/2843) such points in Python for a cross-correlation, this might get you started. The rest should be some [signal processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_processing). A hint might be [findpeaks](http://de.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html).