# VSE: disable snapping to frames for sound?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

Is there any way to move a sound strip or slide its content without snapping it to the frames? It makes no sense for a sound strip to behave like that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be a clear no:

[VSE: Can I move an audio track in smaller increments than one frame?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24052/vse-can-i-move-an-audio-track-in-smaller-increments-than-one-frame)

[Which animation features don't support sub-frames?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36605/which-animation-features-dont-support-sub-frames)

There is a rightclickselect proposal to implement it:

https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/cgbbbc/